# What replaces BesselJPrimeZeros[n, k] in current versions of Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

In older versions of Mathematica, there was a function called `BesselJPrimeZeros`  used to find the zeros of the derivative of BesselJ function.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionZeros.html

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The package that the above refers to, I think is this

http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6777/

But it is so old. Before I try to see if it will even work on 11.3, I thought to ask since current version of Mathematica 11.3 only has `BesselJZeros` but no `BesselJPrimeZeros`. So I assumed WRI must have put the functionality of `BesselJPrimeZeros` in some other function? if not, why was this function removed? It is useful. Now I need to find number of zeros of `J'(z)` and instead of using root finder, it would be better to have used the above function.

**My question is**: To find zeros of `J'(z)` should one use the above old package, of is there another build-in way in 11.3 to do this that I might have missed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no direct replacement for the BesselZeros package functionality, however it still works with version 11.3.

```
?BesselJPrimeZeros
```

> BesselJPrimeZeros[nu, n] gives a list of the first n zeros of the derivative of the order nu BesselJ function, for nu >= -1. BesselJPrimeZeros[nu, {m, n}] gives a list of the mth through the nth zeros.

```
BesselJPrimeZeros[2, 5]

(* {3.05424, 6.70613, 9.96947, 13.1704, 16.3475} *)

NSolve[D[BesselJ[2, z], z] == 0 && 0 < z < 18, z]

(* {{z -> 3.05424}, {z -> 6.70613}, {z -> 9.96947}, 
    {z -> 13.1704}, {z -> 16.3475}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. So I ignored the message `General::obspkg: NumericalMath BesselZeros is now obsolete. The legacy version being loaded may conflict with current functionality. See the Compatibility Guide for updating information.` that comes up when loading the package. Will keep my fingers crossed :) it would be  good if WRI would add this function back to Mathematica as it was there before.

Comment: If you have a look at the code, although well written and documented, a number of issues are identified. Using `NSolve` (as suggested by @ilian) is very general—and you can even use `Solve` instead. One could insist that there should be built-in code for the zeros of all special functions, and all derivatives. But, more generally, instead of just derivatives one has to solve secular equations (see e.g https://wolfr.am/Whyte for an example), which you could not possibly expect to include.